# How to have an optional trailing closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to write a function that I can call with trailing closure syntax like so:

```
func hello( message: String, closure: (( msg: String ) -> Void)?) {

   println( "called hello with: \(message)" );

   closure?( msg: message );

}
```

I would expect to be able to call this function with a closure:

```
hello( "abc" ) { msg in

    let a = "def";

    println("Called callback with: \(msg) and I've got: \(a)");

};
```

And also without the closure, since it's optional:

```
hello( "abc" )
```

The latter doesn't work. It says I can't call hello with an argument list of (String).

I'm using XCode 6.3.2 and I tested this code within a playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you've got your definition of optional entirely correct. It doesn't mean you don't need to supply a value for the `closure` argument; it means `closure` can either have a value (of a closure in your case) or be `nil`. Therefore, if you wanted to call `hello` without providing a closure you would write:

```
hello("abc", nil)
```

However, you can achieve what you're after using default parameter values (I'd recommend you have a look at [The Swift Programming Guide: Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)). Your function would be:

```
// Note the `= nil`:
func hello(message: String, closure: ((msg: String ) -> Void)? = nil) {
    println("called hello with: \(message)")

    closure?(msg: message)
}


// Example usage:
hello("abc")
hello("abc") { println($0) }
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. I was wrongly assuming the trailing closure would automatically be assumed to be nil if not provided.